# How do I set a link for the content type field?

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

I have created the view and display to page, but now I want to click on the content title and open this image on new view or page.

[image: screenshot]

How can I set the path in the view and change the path from node/15 to a custom URL with title, for example artist-works/Robert-Boynes/Infinite-Red?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you want to have the `node/15` always be shown as `artist-works/Robert-Boynes/Infinite-Red`, in the browser address bar? Or is this just for this Views? If it's just for these Views, what is the purpose of showing the image again when it's shown here in the Views? Can you give more background on what you want to achieve? Show image larger across the screen?

Comment: this is the flow of the website ,ya its just for the view .

Comment: In this case edit the node 15, in URL Path Settings set the URL Alias. In your case url alias should be "artist-works/Robert-Boynes/Infinite-Red" so that if user click on link node/15 it will see the page url "artist-works/Robert-Boynes/Infinite-Red".